# UPDATE/CREATE with LEFT JOIN multiple at a time

Tags: mysql, join

I'm working now on some dictionary and i'm downloading source from multiple dictionaries into mysql database.

I have two tables:

Words

`ID and Word`

ie. VALUES:

`123, "Hakunamatata"`

`332, "Boom"`

Source

`ID, WordID and Numerical` ie. VALUES:

`1, 123, 7676552`

`2, 332, 651365`

Now, i would like to update data in Source this way:

- find ID in Words WHERE Word = "example"
- put datum (WordID, "Number") into Source

BUT

If there is no such Word in Words - create it.

I need to do about 100000 of queries of this type, but it does not need to be very fast ;)

I've tried to do something like this:

`REPLACE INTO`sjp-dict`.`Words
`LEFT JOIN`sjp-dict`.`Source-Wiktionary
    `ON`Words`.ID =`Source-Wiktionary`.WordID
SET` 
Word`= IF(`Word`IS NULL, "Apulia",`Word`),`
WordID`= IF(`Source-Wiktionary`.WordID IS NULL AND`Word`= "Apulia",`Words`.ID,`WordID`),` 
WikiWordID`= IF(`Word`= "Apulia", 123, WikiWordID)`

But it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Done with two sql commands:

`$sql  = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO Words (Word) VALUES '. $sql_words;
$sql2 = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO "Source-Wiktionary" (WordID, WikiWordID) VALUES '. $sql_values;`

Where WordID is definied by

`SELECT ID FROM Words WHERE Word = "'. strtolower($cma[2]). '" LIMIT 1`